# How can I move list item to top when we mark the list item in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have list items in SwiftUI, and I want to move item on top when I set the favorite item with star icon, and I want to repeat it for second item again, is it possible? I know there is example for moving the row, but I do not understand how I will do like that.

**Model:**

```
struct Restaurant: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var image: String
    var isFavorite: Bool = false
  
}
```

**BasicImageRow:**

```
    struct BasicImageRow: View {

    var restaurant: Restaurant
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(restaurant.image)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                .cornerRadius(5)
            Text(restaurant.name)
          
            if restaurant.isFavorite {
                Spacer()
                
                Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(.yellow)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
  
    @State private var selectedRestaurant: Restaurant?
    
  @State private  var restaurants = [ Restaurant(name: "Cafe Deadend", image: "cafedeadend"),
                  Restaurant(name: "Homei", image: "homei"),
                  Restaurant(name: "Teakha", image: "teakha"),
                  Restaurant(name: "Cafe Loisl", image: "cafeloisl"),
                  Restaurant(name: "Petite Oyster", image: "petiteoyster"),
                  Restaurant(name: "For Kee Restaurant", image: "forkeerestaurant"),

            ]

 
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(restaurants) { restaurant in
                BasicImageRow(restaurant: restaurant)
                    .contextMenu {
                        
                        Button(action: {
                            // mark the selected restaurant as check-in
                            self.checkIn(item: restaurant)
                        }) {
                            HStack {
                                Text("Check-in")
                                Image(systemName: "checkmark.seal.fill")
                            }
                        }
                        
                        Button(action: {
                            // delete the selected restaurant
                            self.delete(item: restaurant)
                        }) {
                            HStack {
                                Text("Delete")
                                Image(systemName: "trash")
                            }
                        }
                        
                        Button(action: {
                            // mark the selected restaurant as favorite
                            self.setFavorite(item: restaurant)
                        }) {
                            HStack {
                                Text("Favorite")
                                Image(systemName: "star")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.selectedRestaurant = restaurant
                    }
                    .actionSheet(item: self.$selectedRestaurant) { restaurant in
                        
                        ActionSheet(title: Text("What do you want to do"), message: nil, buttons: [
                            
                            .default(Text("Mark as Favorite"), action: {
                                self.setFavorite(item: restaurant)
                            }),
                            
                            .destructive(Text("Delete"), action: {
                                self.delete(item: restaurant)
                            }),
                            
                            .cancel()
                        ])
                    }
            }
           
        }
    }
   
    
    private func setFavorite(item restaurant: Restaurant) {
        if let index = self.restaurants.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == restaurant.id }) {
            self.restaurants[index].isFavorite.toggle()
        }
    }
   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated: Amination position changing for favorite toggle**

You just need to update restaurants inside `withAnimation` block, SwiftUI will know how to animate them with their id

```
ForEach(restaurants) { restaurant in
    Button(action: {
        withAnimation {
            var selectedRestaurant = restaurant
            selectedRestaurant.isFavorite.toggle()
            restaurants = restaurants.filter { $0.id != restaurant.id }
            let index = selectedRestaurant.isFavorite ? 0 : restaurants.firstIndex { $0.isFavorite == false }
            restaurants.insert(selectedRestaurant, at: index ?? 0)
        }
    }) {
        BasicImageRow(restaurant: restaurant)
    }.buttonStyle(.automatic)
}
```

Here is the full sample code (you can try on on Previews)

```
struct Restaurant: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var image: String
    var isFavorite: Bool = false
}

extension Restaurant: Equatable {}

struct BasicImageRow: View {
    var restaurant: Restaurant
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(restaurant.name)
            if restaurant.isFavorite {
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(.yellow)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var restaurants = [
        Restaurant(name: "Cafe Deadend", image: "cafedeadend"),
        Restaurant(name: "Homei", image: "homei"),
        Restaurant(name: "Teakha", image: "teakha"),
        Restaurant(name: "Cafe Loisl", image: "cafeloisl"),
        Restaurant(name: "Petite Oyster", image: "petiteoyster"),
        Restaurant(name: "For Kee Restaurant", image: "forkeerestaurant"),
    ]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(restaurants) { restaurant in
                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation {
                        var selectedRestaurant = restaurant
                        selectedRestaurant.isFavorite.toggle()
                        restaurants = restaurants.filter { $0.id != restaurant.id }
                        let index = selectedRestaurant.isFavorite ? 0 : restaurants.firstIndex { $0.isFavorite == false }
                        restaurants.insert(selectedRestaurant, at: index ?? 0)
                    }
                }) {
                    BasicImageRow(restaurant: restaurant)
                }.buttonStyle(.automatic)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: favorite toggle animation]

Comment: @tnx, but it is not work

Comment: I've tested it before making answer so it should work. I've updated my answer in case you want some animation for it.

Comment: tnx so much for your answer,  appreciated,  but it ha is a bit problem,  when you click the favorite item,  it again move to top,  my main problem is,  when you select favorite it have to move top,  when you select favorite item,  it has to be unfavorite and move to belove,  is it possible?

Comment: i've updated my answer, please check if that's what you need

Comment: tnx so much let me try :)

Comment: it is the best solution for me tnx so so much, appreciated